# Convert Div element as image, ii should support in IE 7 & 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, html5-canvas, jqplot, excanvas

I am using jqplot charting library to draw the chart in my ASP.NET MVC application.Inside the div element, rendering the chart.I am trying to convert the div element as image, export to pdf document.
For IE 9  and later, jqplotToImageElem() method [support canvas browsers only] is working fine and able to export.
For IE 7 & 8 it is not working as expected, since it is using excanvas.js to render the chart.
Is there any workaround to implement this for IE 7 & 8 browsers?

Comment: It's too much work to support older versions of Internet Explorer, since they don't comply with recent standards (IE8 was release almost four years ago). Is it imperative to support it? in the latest project I worked on we decided to just present a splash screen to IE<9 users so they can download the latest version of their favorite browser

Answer (score 0):

For IE<9 users you have multiple possibilities:

1. Use node.js on the server to generate your jqplot image and then let them download that image off the server.
2. Require that they install Google Chrome Frame **which will works within IE<9** to give it modern capabilities like canvas.  See: https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/
3. Since jqPlot evidently works but doesn't print in IE<9, just have those users print using a screen capture program.
4. Microsoft recently realized that their non-modern IE's were a liability to the web and has begun auto-updating older IE users to modern versions of IE (See: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/the-skinny-on-ies-update-policy/).  So as @amhed suggests, you could require that your users "get with the program" and update to at least IE9.  Alternatively, update to Chrome, Firefox, any-modern-browser.
5. There would be very few clients you couldn't service with #1-4 (but we're looking at you "certain banking institutions" who run on XP and for security reasons & disallow browser upgrades).  But for those few clients, you might have to use a GDI-based charting program rather that jqplot.

Comment: How to generate jqplot image using node.js?Please share the link related to this.